# Cannot invoke "com.example.cafe.JWT.JwtUtil.extractUsername(String)" because "this.jwtUtil" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

The error I've encountered:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.cafe.JWT.JwtUtil.extractUsername(String)" because "this.jwtUtil" is null, suggests that the jwtUtil field in the UserServiceImpl class is not being properly injected.

```
- class UserServiceImpl -
```

```
@Autowired
private  JwtUtil jwtUtil;
@Autowired
private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
@Service
@Slf4j

    public ResponseEntity<String> login(Map<String, String> requestMap) {
        log.info("Inside login");
        try {
            //AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration);
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(requestMap.get("email"), (requestMap.get("password"))));
            if(authentication.isAuthenticated()){
                if(customerUsersDetailsService.getUserDetail().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"token\":\"" +
                            jwtUtil.generateToken(customerUsersDetailsService.getUserDetail().getEmail(),customerUsersDetailsService.getUserDetail().getRole()) + "\"}",HttpStatus.OK);
                } else {
                    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"message\":\""+"Wait for admin approval." + "\"}", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception exception){
            log.error("{}", exception);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"message\":\""+"Bad credentials." + "\"}", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

```
- class JwtUtil  -
```

```
@Service
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @Slf4j   
public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails){        
 final String username = extractUsername(token);        
 return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !this.isTokenExpired(token));     }
@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<UserWrapper>> getAllUsers() {
       try {
           if(jwtFilter.isAdmin()) return new ResponseEntity<>(userDao.getAllUser(), HttpStatus.OK);
           else return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
       } catch (Exception exception){
           exception.printStackTrace();
       }
       return new ResponseEntity<>(new ArrayList<>(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
   }
```

Comment: What is your question or exact problem? What behaviour would you expect? Where does the error exactly occur? Can you provide a [mre]? Independently of your actual problem I would recommend that you switch to constructor injection, it makes testing easier and prevents other problems with e.g. circular dependencies that could cause troubles.

Comment: Firstly explain the issue that you're having